# Laravel: Route 'Login' not defined?

Tags: php, laravel

When trying to go to an auth required middleware page I'm getting `'Route [login] not defined'` the problem is, my login route isn't called 'login' and I don't want it to be called login.

Here are my routes...

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'User'], function() {
    Route::get('/home', ['uses' => 'HomeController@getView', 'as' => 'frontend.user.home']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest', 'namespace' => 'Guest'], function() {
    Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'LoginController@getView', 'as' => 'frontend.guest.login']);
    Route::post('/login', ['uses' => 'LoginController@onPost', 'as' => 'frontend.guest.login']);
});
```

How can I get it to stop requiring route 'login' and start requiring my custom one 'frontend.guest.login' ??

Comment: change your auth middleware

Comment: Share code, where you are calling get route on your laravel template

Comment: Are you calling as `route("login")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should fix your following route names:

```
Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'LoginController@getView', 'as' => 'frontend.guest.login']);
Route::post('/login', ['uses' => 'LoginController@onPost', 'as' => 'frontend.guest.login']);
```

Notice that, you've used `frontend.guest.login` for both (get/post) routes which is wrong, instead you should use unique names for example: `frontend.guest.get.login` for `Route::get()` and `frontend.guest.post.login` for `Route::post()`.

Then, in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class, create/override the following method:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401)
                : redirect()->guest(route('frontend.guest.get.login'));
}
```

Also, use the `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;` statement at the top of your class to import `AuthenticationException` class in your `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

Also, change every use case of `frontend.guest.login` to appropriate route name, use `frontend.guest.post.login` for form submission/action and `frontend.guest.get.login` to show the form or for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Laravel's default `Authenticate` middleware throws an `AuthenticationException` and Laravel's default way to handle this exception is to do this:

```
return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

You will find this code in the `unauthenticated` method of `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`, which your default `App\Exceptions\Handler` should extend.

You are able to override this behaviour simply by providing your own `unauthenticated` method in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    // The rest of your Handler class here...

    public function unauthenticated()
    {
        // Add your implementation here
    }
}
```